# wp_option table error while importing

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am importing a huge database manually and i have a problem. The error it very vague to me, as i am not much familiar with mysql. The error says the following

[image]

Its such data that i am unable to comprehend, where to find the error. It cannot be `option_id`, as its `auto_increment`. What is the problem? When it says `Duplicate entry 1 for key primary`?

Comment: Your database is already populated and you are trying to insert duplicates of "keys" that have to be unique. Please explain the situation in more detail. I am sure there is information missing.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes i see the data in that table :) , i have imported database manually,the reason i am importing it manually is because i had error when using phpmyadmin-import tab with [error](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0501xnhw9f) now trying to make the website work, the wp_config has right credentials but when i load the website url, its a blank page.

Comment: Your import is bad. Start over from an empty database.

Comment: @s_ha_dum but the error i mentioned. that is what i get,when i import a full db using phpmyadmin import tab. how can i get rid of [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0501xnhw9f) error

Comment: That is a different error than the one in the question and it looks like you have a quote mismatch-- bad export perhaps, corrupt file, encoding mismatch... Hard to say, but probably not WordPress specific.

Comment: @s_ha_dum that was the database backup, i got from web hosting ppl. how can i know if its corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my own problem, while its was a very struggling effort.If your database is corrupt, but you want to restore your site. Just open your database in a any program like TextEdit, Notepad++ and make sure you copy the basic databases mention [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png) in a new database, that will at least make your website up and running back as it was :)